# Is there a UIImagePicker event for "picture taken" before preview?

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm recording data while the camera view is open, and want to remember the data at the moment a picture is taken.

But if I wait for didFinishPickingImage:, the data is already too old, because the user can stay in the preview-dialog very long.

Is it possible to see somehow, when the preview starts/gets cancelled?

I'm using an overlay view with the default camera buttons, don't really want to invent the interface (buttons/flash/focus/rear-front/preview) from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you are using a standard UIImagePickerController then the only events you get are the two delegate methods.

There is a key for getting the photo's meta data. This metadata may contain a time stamp. Perhaps you can correlate this times tamp with the data you are collecting.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i feared. Keeping some data is bad, because I don't know how long the user waits to accept the image. Will have to test if I can keep all data since the picker was started. Will accept this answer if nobody has a better idea.